# Value of $p$ for the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^p}dx$ to converge

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

We need to find the value of $p$ for which the below integral converges:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^p}dx
$$

Let us take
$$
f(x)=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^p}
$$
and
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}
$$
We can see that
$$
f(x)<g(x) \text{ for }0<x\leq1
$$
So
$$
\int_0^1f(x)dx<\int_0^1g(x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p}=\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\left[x^{-p+1}\right]_0^a=\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)\lim_{a\rightarrow0}(a^{-p+1})
$$
The limit exists only if $-p+1>0$ or
$$
p<1
$$
But this isn't the right answer. The right answer is $p<2$. We can get that by taking
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{x^{.5p}}
$$
This second choice of $g(x)$ was a guess and just happened to get me the right result. But the guess was not due to any intelligent methodology. I think, testing via direct convergence test or limit convergence test is not the way to go here, since that would require selecting the 'best' comparing function.

Next, using integration by parts
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^p}dx=\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\left[\frac{x^{1-p}}{1-p}\ln(1+x)\right]_a^1-\frac{1}{1-p}\int_0^1\frac{x^{1-p}}{1+x}dx
$$
Take the first term here
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\left[\frac{x^{1-p}}{1-p}\ln(1+x)\right]_a^1=\left[\frac{\ln2}{1-p}-\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{a^{1-p}\ln(1+a)}{1-p}\right]
$$
This limit exists for a max value of $p=2$, the correct answer (We can go full L'Hopital for $p=2$ and get the limit).

Let's take
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^{1-p}}{1+x}dx
$$
for $p\leq1$, it can be easily seen that the integral converges (it's a logarithm or a polynomial).

But when $p>1$, I don't know how to approach the problem. If $p$ assumed just integral values, then I could go via partial fractions and show that $p<2$. But what about non-integral values of $p$?

Comment: The point here is that the only problem for convergence is around zero. However, you can show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for $x\in [0;1]$, we gave $$\ln(1+x)\leq Cx.$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: The estimate you get by the fundamental theorem of calculus $$\ln(1+x)= \ln(1+0) +\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+s}ds \leq 0+\int_0^x 1 ds = x.$$

Comment: Please don't use `\displaystyle` in the question title.

Comment: @soupless but why?

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa I'm sorry that I forgot to include the link. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $0\leq\log(1+x)\leq x$ for $x\in[0,1]$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x^{p}}dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x}{x^{p}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x^{p-1}}dx<\infty
\end{align*}
if $p-1<1$, that is, $p<2$.

Let us argue about $p\geq 2$. Integration by parts gives
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x^{p}}dx=\dfrac{\log 2}{1-p}+\dfrac{1}{p-1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x}\dfrac{1}{x^{p-1}}dx.
\end{align*}
The last integral diverges when $p-1\geq 1$, that is, $p\geq 2$.

Comment: The last integral is where I have the problem. Could you please explain? Kindly take a look at the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x}\dfrac{1}{x^{p-1}}dx\geq\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+1}\dfrac{1}{x^{p-1}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x^{p-1}}dx=\infty$ for $p\geq 2$.

Comment: For $p>2$, $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\log(1+a)}{a^{p-2}}=\infty$ and hence the boundary term becomes $\dfrac{1}{p-1}\cdot\infty=\infty$ and also the integral is $\dfrac{1}{p-1}\cdot\infty$, so the total is still $\infty$.

Comment: I got another question. If I choose $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$ for the last integral, then I'd get $p\leq1$. If I happened to luckily choose $g(x)=\frac{1}{2x^{p-1}}$, then I'd correctly arrive at $p<2$. What I'm trying to say is, this seems like a trial and error, when it comes to choosing $g(x)$ and personally I feel like using comparison tests to determine $p$ is not a good idea as it involves some luck or foresight. How do we go about systematically? Like considering cases when $p-1=0$, $p-1<0$ and $p-1>0$?

Comment: You should start to look for when it is convergent, the first integral the "best" you can say about the convergence of $\int\log(1+x)/x^{p}$ is $p<2$. So you turn out to best argue that it is divergent for all $p\geq 2$. Integration by parts gives $1/(1+x)\cdot 1/x^{p-1}$. Since $1/(1+x)$ has no singularity on $[0,1]$, so just omit it, and hence we only look at $\int 1/x^{p-1}$ and this is divergent exactly when $p-1\geq 1$ and so you are done.